# Component: Button publish not working

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.7

i follow series "Developing an MVC Component" on https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component, but when i click to publish button, i have an error "Fatal error: Call to undefined method JmsMessagesModelMessages::publish() in E:\xampp\htdocs\joomla37\libraries\legacy\controller\admin.php on line 210". Somebody help me. I using joomla 3.7.5. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `$name` and `$prefix` variables that are passing over `getModel` function on your controller.

`$name` = NAME_OF_YOUR_EDIT_VIEW
`$prefix` = COMPONENT_NAME + `Model`

Answer (score 1):

> "Fatal error: Call to undefined method JmsMessagesModelMessages::publish() in E:\xampp\htdocs\joomla37\libraries\legacy\controller\admin.php on line 210"

Like the error says, you don't have implemented a publish() function in your model.

Make one that changes the state for the column like you want on the database and it will work.

Comment: @NotToday You're welcome :D